# Why is the Frequency Array saving garbage values?

Tags: c, arrays

So There are Three Arrays:- UserArray, UniqueArray and FrequencyArray.
ArraySize is the size of UserArray.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
      int ArraySize;
      scanf("%d",&ArraySize);
      int UserArray[ArraySize],UniqueArray[ArraySize],FrequencyArray[ArraySize];
      for(int i=0;i<ArraySize;i++)
      {
           scanf("%d",&UserArray[i]);
      }
      int SizeOfUniqueArray=0;
      for(int i=0;i<ArraySize;i++)
      {
              int j;
              for(j=0;j<i;j++)
              {
                      if(UserArray[i]==UserArray[j])
                      {
                              break;
                      }
              }
              if(j==i)
              {
                      UniqueArray[SizeOfUniqueArray]=UserArray[i];
                      SizeOfUniqueArray++;
              }
      }
      int count=0,k=0; 
      for(int i=0;i<ArraySize;i++) {
             if(UserArray[i]==UniqueArray[k])
             {
                     count++;
                     if(i == ArraySize-1)
                     {
                            FrequencyArray[k]=count;
                            count=0;
                            k++;
                            if(k <= ArraySize)
                            {
                                   i=0;
                            }
                     }
              }
       }
}
```

UserArray is a user defined array which stores integers say 1,2,3,4,8,4,3,1,5,6,7,1,2,6,2.
So ArraySize = 15.
UniqueArray contains the unique numbers of UserArray meaning:- 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8.
now the below given code is the code to save the frequency of the unique numbers in UserArray.
like the first element of UniqueArray is 1. 1 is repeated 3 times in the UserArray so the first element of FrequencyArray is 3. But this code is saving garbage values in the FrequencyArray.
I want to know why?
why is the above program saving garbage values?

We can save The values in FrequencyArray through this code:-

```
for(int i=0;i<SizeOfUniqueArray;i++)
{
        int count=0;
        for(int j=0;j<ArraySize;j++)
        {
                if(UserArray[j]==UniqueArray[i])
                {
                        count++;
                }
        }
        FrequencyArray[i]=count;
}
```

Comment: How do you initialize the arrays you use? Please try to create a [mcve] to show us. And please learn how to use a debugger to step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: Do you have a limit on the maximum size of the integer that can be entered? What is this limit if any?

Comment: i have done some edits. hope this much is sufficient.

Comment: Please read the [mre] link. What you show is more of a code puzzle.

Comment: The codes you have written are not clear. If you could add comments to it, it would be more readable. Also the are the elements in the array in a particular range? if yes then you can do the task in just two arrays. One array would be the unique array and the other would be Frequency Array. If the frequency is 1 then it is a unique element.

Comment: The variable p is not defined in the line  UniqueArray[p]=UserArray[i]; Also the nested for loop should be i from 0 to n and j from i+1 to n.

Comment: i am done with the edit.

Comment: i think this much should be good enough to understand

Comment: The only array that I can see being fully initialized is `UserArray`. The other arrays may contain uninitialized elements. Please initialize them at definition (like e.g. `int UniqueArray[ArraySize] = { 0 };`)

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure that the algorithm that you have will work to get the UniqueArrays. Here I have suggested an alternative algorithm.

The code below is based on the assumption that the input numbers are within a range of `0 <= UserArray[i] <= MAXINT`. Also `MAXINT` should not be very large or too much memory is required.

```
#define MAXINT  100           // The maximum unsigned integer that is supported.  
int FrequencyArray[MAXINT+1]; 

int main(void)
{
    int ArraySize;
    scanf("%d",&ArraySize);
    int UserArray[ArraySize];
    int UniqueArray[ArraySize];
    for(int i=0;i<ArraySize;i++)
    {
         scanf("%d",&UserArray[i]);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<ArraySize;i++) {
        FrequencyArray[UserArray[i]]++;
    }

    int k=0;
    for (int i=0; i<=MAXINT; i++)
    {
        if (FrequencyArray[i]!=0)
        {
            UniqueArray[k++] = i;
        }
    }
    int UniqueArraySize = k;    // for further use or printing.
}
```

If you require to support negative elements, then a shift of the `FrequencyArray` is required.

If `MAXINT` grows very large then this algorithm is not suitable and other hashing algorithms are suggested.

Answer (score 2):

When you create `UniqueArray` you get `SizeOfUniqueArray` unique integers

```
 UniqueArray[] == { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 }
```

When you want to count the frequency of each unique number you start by going through `UserArray` from 0 to `ArraySize` and look in `UniqueArray` but it should be the other way around.

Instead you should go through your `UniqueArray` from 0 to `SizeOfUniqueArray` and check how many times each number occurs in `UserArray`:

```
for (k = 0; k < SizeOfUniqueArray; ++k)
{
  int count = 0;
  for (j = 0; j < ArraySize; ++j)
  {
    if ( UniqueArray[k] == UserArray[j] ) ++count;
```

A final note, initialize all your arrays and variables before using them, it is good practice in C.

As an alternative approach to keep things together you could instead of having to unrelated arrays FrequencyArray and UniqueArray have an array of structs which contain the number number and number of times it occurs, this you could then fill in already when you go through the numbers the first time.

```
typedef struct
{
  int value;
  int freq;
}
UniqueValues;

UniqueValues UniqueArray[ArraySize] = { {0,0} };
```

Comment: I know how to do it using two for loops..I am looking for a solution to do it with one loop and multiple if statements

Comment: I gave the code snippet of how to do this using two for loops at the end of the question